# Why does this integral not contradict Fubini's Theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I have the integral: $$\int^{1}_{0}\int^{\infty}_{1} (e^{-xy}-2e^{-2xy}) \,\text{d}y~\text{d}x$$, and I know that the order of integration cannot be interchanged, but why does this not contradict Fubini's Theorem? Could someone explain it in details please? Thanks.

Comment: Fubini's theorem has some conditions on the integrand before one knows that you can interchange the integral signs.. Do they apply here?

Comment: I think I get the problem here is that the function does not belong to $L^1([0,1]\times [1, \infty))$, but how do I exactly show this?

Comment: By computing the integral of its absolute value.

Comment: @Did So the integral of the absolute value is not finite？

Comment: @EmmaJ If you arrived at that conclusion, you should be done. What is the definition of L^1 that you are working with?